# Java Method undoing Algorithm

Tags: java

What I am trying to do is read a file and use the `StringBuilder` to reverse the order of what ever is inside the file which is a line of string words.
I got it to work inside the while loop but when I add it to a method it just prints out the original file text.

Here is the code that works;

```
// File being read....
while ((currentString = s.next()) != null) {
    a.insert(0, currentString);
    a.insert(0," ");
}
```

Print

```
line. this reads it hope I file. this read will program This
```

Here is the code that does not work;

```
// File being read....
while ((currentString = s.next()) != null) {
    System.out.print(reverse(currentString));
}
```

Method

```
public static StringBuilder reverse(String s){
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
    a.insert(0, s);
    a.insert(0," ");
}
```

Print

```
This program will read this file. I hope it reads this line.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new `StringBuilder a` every time you call `reverse()`. You need to keep a reference to `StringBuilder` in order to correctly append all the Strings to it.

```
// File being read....
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();

while ((currentString = s.next()) != null) {
    reverse(a, currentString);
}

// ...

public static void reverse(StringBuilder a, String currentString) {
    a.insert(0, s);
    a.insert(0," ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new StringBuilder and printing it as you're reading each word.
You'll want to build up the string and then print after all the reading.
If you want to reverse in a method but read each word outside the method then you could give the current StringBuilder to your reverse method like

```
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
while ((currentString = s.next()) != null) {
    reverse(total, currentString);
}
System.out.print(currentString);

public static void reverse(StringBuilder total, String s) {
    total.insert(0, s);
    total.insert(0, " ");
}
```